# Customized WebVIew In Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to set font of web view to `marathi`. Can anybody tell me how to that? Here is my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.web);
web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/welcome.html");
```

Comment: What if you search yourself first: [android webview with custom font](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+webview+with+custom+font)?

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlData = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>" + htmlData;

// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file

web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

OR

**simple way to do**

Put your html and css in your **/assets/** folder, then load the html file like so:

```
web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourHtml.html");
```

then in your html you can reference your css in the usual way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

And for custom fonts you can use `@font-face` in that `css` like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'akshar';
    src: url('fonts/akshar.ttf');
}

body {font-family: 'akshar';}
```

OR TRY OUT THIS

```
head="<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'akshar';src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/akshar.TTF');}body {font-family: 'akshar';}</style></head>";
                HtmlString = "<html>"+head+"<body>"+content+"</body></html>";  
MyWebView.loadData(HtmlString, "contentType=text/html", "charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sir can you please tell me this according to my code

Comment: I did that but still it show boxes

Comment: Did you made a font face for marathi ttf?

Comment: yes 

@font-face { 
    font-family: "akshar"; 
    src: url('akshar.TTF'); 
}
.phon, .unicode
{
    display: inline;    
    font-family: 'akshar', Verdana, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style:normal;
    color: black;
}

tell me is that right??

Comment: sir can you give me your email-id, I'll send you my code

Answer (score -2):

> You can try this out

```
Webview wv = new webview(context);
WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUserAgentString(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
```

Comment: where should I suppose to put my .ttf file

Comment: did you read the question?